# Replace last character in a large file (whole file is a single line)

Tags: linux, text, sed, character

I have a 60GB file that's a single line.

All I need to do is to change the last "," (the last character in the file).

The thing is `sed` can't process it because it's all in a single line and it fails to allocate memory.

```
// file.txt
[0] ...mple12,sample13),(sample21,sample22,sample23),

// desired file.txt
[0] ...mple12,sample13),(sample21,sample22,sample23);
```

I get an error `Couldn't re-allocate memory`

Comment: you can open it in one editor and do the modification. If it was just an one time job.

Comment: it's actually something that'll repeat often as a part of a pipeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such cases, a stream oriented approach might help.
Can easily be achieved with shell:

```
# First remove last character
head -c -1 < file.txt > file2.txt
# then add new last character ';' to the end
echo -n ";" >> file2.txt
```

Please note: If there is a CR at the end of the file, you need to use 'head -c -2' instead.

A one-liner would be:

```
head -c -1 <file.txt | (cat - ; echo ';') > file2.txt
```

Comment: good answer! Just a reminder to O.P. you'll need to have the space for 2 60GB files, you can't redirect back to your original filename, as that will erase the file. i.e. DON'T `.....) > file1.txt`. Good luck to all.